# isset() in php not working

Tags: php, mysql, isset

May I know why the echo in my isset block is not appearing?
Is it because the way I echo my html code in php? Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
<?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[7] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>
              <ul class=\"form-style-1\">
                <select name=\"option_update\" class=\"field-select\">
                    <option value=\"approved\">Approve</option>
                    <option value=\"declined\">Decline</option>
                    <option value=\"pending\">Pending</option>
                </select>
                <input type=\"submit\" value=\"update\" name=\"update_value\"/>
              </ul>
            </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
?>
</table>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['update_value'])){

        echo "test";
    }

?>
```

Comment: post you http request

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: don't see a form tag - `<form method="post">`

Comment: @Sean is right ! Please show your complete form code.

Comment: @Sean thank you man, just adding that line completed my code, cant believe i overlooked it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[7] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>
            <form action="#" method="post"> 
              <ul class=\"form-style-1\">
                <select name=\"option_update\" class=\"field-select\">
                    <option value=\"approved\">Approve</option>
                    <option value=\"declined\">Decline</option>
                    <option value=\"pending\">Pending</option>
                </select>
                <input type=\"submit\" value=\"update\" name=\"update_value\"/>
             **</form>**
              </ul>
            </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
?>
</table>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['update_value'])){

        echo "test";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you man, cant believe i missed out that part!! haha.. accepted

Answer (score 0):

To get variables from $_POST, you have to submit them from HTML Form

```
<form method="post">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp